# Removing gap between chart cloumns in ui5

Tags: sapui5

I am working on sap fiori project which displays data in chart format. In a dual series chart, I want to remove the gap in between columns, which you can see below:

[image: this gap I am talking about]

I tried searching for attributes for vizframe.

```
<layout:flexContent>
            <viz:Popover id="idPopOver"></viz:Popover>
            <viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}"
                height='100%' width="100%" vizType='column'>
                <viz:dataset>
                    <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{/milk}">
                        <viz.data:dimensions>
                            <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Week"
                                value="{Week}" />
                        </viz.data:dimensions>
                        <viz.data:measures>
                            <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Revenue"
                                value="{Revenue}" />
                            <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Cost"
                                value="{Cost}" />
                        </viz.data:measures>
                    </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                </viz:dataset>

                <viz:feeds>
                    <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='valueAxisFeed' uid="valueAxis" type="Measure"
                        values="Revenue" />
                    <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='categoryAxisFeed' uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension"
                        values="Week" />
                </viz:feeds>
            </viz:VizFrame>
        </layout:flexContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **vizProperties** and set **plotArea** => **gap** => **innerGroupSpacing**

```
<viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}"
              height='100%' width="100%" vizType='column'
              vizProperties="{ plotArea : {gap: {innerGroupSpacing:0}} }">
```